# Crash a UITableView after reloading it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView which is calling a NSMutableArray for it's data.
All is working well, until I pop this page again and again and again.
After popping this page for let's say 50 times my page crashes.

I'm at a loss. Anyone know what I'm talking about?

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000034f4 objc_msgSend + 20
1   UIKit                           0x000a9248 -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal)     _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 644
2   UIKit                           0x000a8eac -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] + 44
3   UIKit                           0x0006f480 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1300
4   UIKit                           0x0006ce40 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 200
5   UIKit                           0x00014ab0 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) _layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 32
6   CoreFoundation                  0x000285ba -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:] + 18
7   QuartzCore                      0x0000a61c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 176
8   QuartzCore                      0x0000a2a4 CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 192
9   QuartzCore                      0x00009bb0 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 256
10  QuartzCore                      0x000097d8 CA::Transaction::commit() + 276
11  QuartzCore                      0x000119d8 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 80
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00074244 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 12
13  CoreFoundation                  0x00075d9e __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 494
14  CoreFoundation                  0x000772f6 __CFRunLoopRun + 934
15  CoreFoundation                  0x0001e0bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 220
16  CoreFoundation                  0x0001dfca CFRunLoopRunInMode + 54
17  GraphicsServices                0x00003f88 GSEventRunModal + 188
18  UIKit                           0x00007b40 -[UIApplication _run] + 564
19  UIKit                           0x00005fb8 UIApplicationMain + 964
20  Toernooi.nl                     0x0006e322 main (main.m:14)
21  Toernooi.nl                     0x00002708 start + 32
```

Comment: I'm trying to show some code. but for some reason it will not post my code. first time poster

Comment: Just edit your question and add some code to it, you should be able to do that regardless of how much reputation you have.

Comment: Edit your question and above your answer box there are button click on '{}', and add your code.

Comment: copy your code first then select the " {} " above the answer box then paste your code between ' '